# Team Foundation Server Disable History for User

Tags: azure-devops

Is There a way of blocking a user from seeing the project history. For example i dont want certain users to see other users changes only get code edit code check in.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That's a bad idea..

Comment: i dont want outsourced workers to see anything but the current code or even see each other.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You want to give them ability to make changes/check-in but not look at history. History helps in working as a team. How can you have a team like that?

Comment: its a strange scenario for one user only. The why's and wherefores don't matter to much. Is it possible?.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment above it doesn't make sense to me why you are doing it. You want user to check-in/checkout changes but not look at history. It's weird. Even if you want to do it (for whatever reason) it's not possible to do it in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question.
But there would be a workaround to achieve the goal of isolating code and history to a group of users (Outsourcing group) in TFSVC.

1. Create a branch and gives rights to the target (Outsourcing group) user group for checkin/read... only to that branches.
2. Deny rights to the source branch
3. Automate merge in gated checkin builds on both branches (source and mirrored).
   (You could automate exclusive locks if you want to avoid merge conflicts).

This is not a perfect solution but it works for the purpose.